# Error In a list after upgrading my Sharepoint app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

We have SharePoint provider-hosted app which contain a collections of lists . Every thing was working well when we deploy it for the first time in the client site .Now we changed the type of a field in a list from text to lookup field and upgraded the app in the site. When we try to open the **AllItems.aspx** page of the altered list we found an erorr say **Can not complete this action** As shown :

[image]

this is how the list is created

[image]

the highlighted filed is the filed whose type is converted from text to lookup.

can anyone explain what is the reason of this error and how to solve it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting Text field into a lookup is not supported. So you don't have many options.

One suggestion would be to:

- Keep your old field, keep it's type, but stop using it and make it hidden
- Create a new field and start using it instead

Or (on your own risk)

- Check which field is currently used on the App Web. If it is indeed still Text - you can delete it and run Upgrade one more time.

Comment: Thank you for your sugesstions . How can i know what is supported and what is not supported while upgrading my app ? is there any documentation about it ?